# Subquery in select - non-grouped values in 'IN' clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Assume the following simplified schema:

```
create table main_table
(
    a number,
    b number,
    c number
);

create table other_table
(
    c number,
    d number
)
```

Now, what i want to achieve:
I have a query on main_table, that groups by a,b.
I need to use the "all values of c" in subquery in select clause to get some data from other tables.
I can't join to the other table unfortunately.

Pseudocode would be:

```
select mt.a,
       mt.b,
       (select /* some aggregated value */
          from other_table ot
         where ot.c in (all_values_of_c_within_group)
       )
  from main table mt
 group by mt.a, mt.b
```

There are two ways i know it's possible to handle this:

1. Use join on other_table and then aggregate values from there - unfortunately i can't do it, because of how the real query is structured (3 nested views, 800 sloc, 30 values in group by - long story)
2. Use listagg and then 'delistagg' it with 'instr'. Pseudocode:

---

```
/*(...)*/
(select /* some_aggregated_value */
   from other_table ot
  where instr(',' || listagg(
                     to_char(mt.c), ',') within group (order by 1),
              ',' || ot.c) > 0
)
/*(...)*/
```

But that's just terrible code, and it automatically prevents using any potentially existing indexes on other_table.c.

Is there a syntax to properly get "all values of column within group?

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear without some data and expected results what you are trying to achieve but I think you do what you want using collections:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b6f/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table main_table( a, b, c ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1, 3 FROM DUAL
/

create table other_table( c, d ) AS
  SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 8 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TYPE number_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       ( SELECT LISTAGG( d, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY d )
         FROM   other_table
         WHERE  c MEMBER OF m.cs
       ) ds
FROM   (
  SELECT a,
         b,
         CAST( COLLECT( c ) AS number_table ) AS cs
  FROM   main_table
  GROUP BY a, b
) m
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b6f/3/0)**:

```
| A | B |  DS |
|---|---|-----|
| 1 | 1 | 4,6 |
```

**Query 2**: But it seems simpler to  just use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       LISTAGG( d, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY d ) ds
FROM   main_table m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN other_table o
       ON ( m.c = o.c )
GROUP BY a, b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b6f/3/1)**:

```
| A | B |  DS |
|---|---|-----|
| 1 | 1 | 4,6 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that would work perfectly (well maybe not perfectly performance-wise, but definitely acceptable).
Unfortunately that enforces putting my whole select into a subquery.
I'll wait with accepting the answer in case someone provides something better.

Answer (score 1):

You may just be able to aggregate the subquery, e.g. with sum as the aggregate function:

```
select mt.a,
       mt.b,
       sum(
         (select d
            from other_table ot
           where ot.c = mt.c)
       ) as sum_d
  from main_table mt
 group by mt.a, mt.b;
```

With some made-up data:

```
insert into main_table values (1, 2, 3);
insert into main_table values (1, 2, 4);
insert into main_table values (2, 3, 4);
insert into main_table values (2, 3, 5);
insert into main_table values (2, 3, 6);

insert into other_table values (3, 10);
insert into other_table values (4, 11);
insert into other_table values (5, 12);
insert into other_table values (6, 13);
```

that query gives:

```
         A          B      SUM_D
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          3         36
         1          2         21
```

As you noted, with an extra row:

```
insert into main_table values (2, 3, 4);
```

that query counts a matching `c`'s `d` value multiple times, so you get 47 instead of 36:

```
         A          B      SUM_D
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          3         47
         1          2         21
```

You can add a `distinct`:

```
select mt.a,
       mt.b,
       sum(distinct 
         (select d
            from other_table ot
           where ot.c = mt.c)
       ) as sum_d
  from main_table mt
 group by mt.a, mt.b;

         A          B      SUM_D
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2         21
         2          3         36
```

This assumes that `c`, or at least the combination of `c, d`, is unique in `other_table`.

Comment: That's almost exactly what i want, but there's a problem, when 'C' is not unique within group.

To the made up data,  add another insert into main_table values (2, 3, 4);

Now the aggregate column is 47 for this group - i would want it to still be 36 (that's why i mentioned 'IN' clause in the question).

Comment: @piezol - it wasn't obvious that the de-duplicating effect of `in()` was useful to you. You can (I think) get the same effect with `distinct`; I've added an example.

Comment: The distinct example means 'distinct values of ot.d', what i need is 'values of ot.D for distinct values of mt.C'. Thanks anyway - i'll go with @MT0 solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and should not impose the uniqueness requirements on `other_table` that Alex's answer does.

```
select mt.a,
       mt.b,
       (select sum(d) /* some aggregated value */
          from other_table ot
         where ot.c in ( SELECT mt2.c 
                         FROM main_table mt2 
                         WHERE mt2.a = mt.a AND mt2.b = mt.b
                       ) 
       ) agg
  from main_table mt
 group by mt.a, mt.b;
```

It has to go to `main_table` again for each group, but considering you already are accessing those records, we should be talking about extra logical I/O instead of extra physical I/O.

Using Alex Poole's test data (with the duplicate `MAIN_TABLE` row), I get this in 12c:

```
+---+---+-----+
| A | B | AGG |
+---+---+-----+
| 2 | 3 |  36 |
| 1 | 2 |  21 |
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: Yes it would work - however it means i would have to effectively re-run whole query just to get to the group level that i already should have in 'select' clause.
And another ~~200 lines of code in my case copy-pasted to 'select' :)